# dbt snowflake target doesn't seem to work

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

sorry, I'm very new to dbt, just trying to learn and cant figure out why cant I connect to snowflake. I was able to connect to postgresql database.

Here's my profiles.yml file, I think maybe user is not correct? I can't seem to figure out what is what tbh. Thank you for any help.

```
demo_dbt:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      account: https://eq16839.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com
      database: TEST_DB
      password: myfakepassword
      role: ACCOUNTADMIN
      schema: TEST_SCHEMA
      threads: 1
      type: snowflake
      user: EFLJMYO.YJ19269
      warehouse: COMPUTE_WH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `http://` and `.snowflakecomputing.com` and you should be good. Neither are part of the Snowflake account name.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was indeed the problem.
And I also needed to change the user to the actual username I used when creating snowflake account